# Windows 7 Upgrade vs Full Edition?

Tags: windows-7

My dad already has a copy of Win 7 Pro (full).

If I buy the upgrade edition of Win 7 Pro (student discount), could I use the full disk to install, then enter the new, upgrade key code to activate it?

I can't seem to get a student discount for the full version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a fully licensed qualifying Windows OS on that PC, then that upgrade would not be properly licensed.  Windows upgrade licenses are just that, upgrades to *existing* Windows installations.

However, to answer your question, yes you can.  But, it would not be properly licensed.

Comment: I also have a Win XP Pro upgrade disk (no longer used) could this license it properly?

Comment: Unless there is a fully licensed version of Windows on that PC, then no.

What OS did that PC come pre-installed with?  If it came with pre-installed with XP or Vista, then it would work no problem.  If it's a custom-built PC with no OS pre-installed, then you can always buy an OEM version of Windows (not very expensive).

Comment: As an additional note: An OS doesn't need to be "pre-installed" per se.  The PC itself needs to be licensed.  If the PC has a pre-existing XP or Vista factory sticker on the side of it, then the PC is properly licensed, and you can upgrade it to your hearts content in any manner you wish.

Comment: Well I was thinking about dual-booting with Mac (Bootcamp needs a full disk, since you can't eject the disk drive during the install). Thanks anyway.